# PHP CMS for uploading photos and automatic resizing

Tags: php, mysql, image, content-management-system, resize

Ok, so i'm new to php, but i've built a site for my friends photography in standard html ( http://europeanbob.co.uk/phil/phil.html - best viewed in chrome atm ) and i want to make it as easy as possible for him to upload his photos.

What i want to do is have an admin login where he can select the photos to be uploaded to one of three categories (people, nature & abstract). When the photos are uploaded i also want to run a script to resize them automatically (Something like http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/). So if he uploads "img.jpg", i want to create "img_large.jpg", "img_small.jpg", and "img_thumbnail.jpg".

Also, it needs to import the thumbnails into the relevant gallery page. Is this where having a mySQL database would come in handy?

Basically just looking for a bit of advice or some pointing in the right direction, as i know i should be able to understand it, i'm just feeling a little overwhelmed and don't know where to start.

If there is something out there that will do what i want, then that's great, but if not i'm more than willing to get stuck in and learn what's required.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to learn you should reat about [PHP GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) , 
it's a library which allows you to manipulate pictures (as well resizing them).

About the admin panel you should learn about `cookies` and basic `mysql queries`.
Read about forms and $_POST as well.

If not , You should use [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/).

- It's free
- It's very easy to install
- user friendly
- basic requirements (PHP , DB SQL)
- Support Pages , Posts , Categories and Photos
- There's support (community)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any CMS, you could use other stuff like xml for your simple data structure, but, as you are a beginner, **mySQL** would probaby be easier for you... You can use **SWFupload** for multiple uploads and handle it's onLoad events to create thumbs(needs **jQuery Ajax**). You can find a lot of tools for making thumbs in the Internet, just pick one and set your own resizing parameters. I would make a kind of a form with the category field and the uploader, and each image would have it's own id to identify which category it belongs to and update the category pages accordingly, so that each category page would load it's own images. But it just one of all the possible ways.

To secure your admin panel you should make a login form which uses POST method to verify the entered data and if it's incorrect do a redirection. For additional protection you can check the admin panel url for a unique GET parameter, which knows only admin, and if it's missing also do a redirection. Such method is used in a Joomla plugin for additional admin panel protection. Google **.htaccess** for more info about protection. You can also check **PHP SESSION** to use it in your admin panel, but I'm not sure if you need it.

This is just some basic stuff that you will most likely have to deal with if you decide to make your own gallery.

IMO a CMS is too heavy for such a small project.

Answer (score 0):

A good option for this would be [Drupal](http://drupal.org/). You can get the functionality you need using plugin modules. Just google for "drupal image resize module" or "drupal image upload module" and you'll see some good starting points. Categories, file storage, user login system and permissions etc are all provided out of the box and it's all free :)

Try [Drupal Gardens](http://www.drupalgardens.com/) to have a go on a demo.